# Shuffling a dataframe with constraints in R

Tags: r

I´m currently struggling with shuffling a dataframe in R Studio. Let's say my dataframe looks as follows:

```
x y
0 a
0 a
1 a
1 a
0 b
0 b
1 b
1 b
```

Would it be possible to shuffle the rows but to define, that the four different sequences of variable y (i.e. aa, ab, bb, ba) occur equally often? In total, I have 24 rows in my original dataframe.I hope I could make my problem clear. Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Ema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, however it is not a built-in solution so you will have to code this yourself.

From what I can see from your data frame the `0 a` and `1 a` have 1:1 ratio and same goes for b.
In this case I would recommend grouping the letters in the pairs: `aa, ab, ba, bb` and repeating these pairs three times.
Now shuffle them - this will ensure that every pair occurs with the same frequency. (This only works if I assume that the pairs you wish to check are 1 and 2, 3 and 4, etc... If not and you wish to check 1 and 2, 2 and 3, etc. then I misunderstood. and you can stop reading.)

Now take only lines with (a)s, assign 6 ones and 6 zeroes in your case. Shuffle the a's only.

Repeat for (b)s.

You have your shuffle.